# Excel for loop for automatic copy

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to make a loop to copy a specific selection with a specific interval into a new range or up to a new range.

This is my code:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
Dim c As Integer
c = 0
    For i = 1 To 119 Step 3
        c = c + i + 120
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).Copy Range("A(c)")
    Next i
End Sub
```

but it does not work. Can someone help me please?

Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).Copy Cells(c, 1)

Comment: how can I make the same loop only for selection? It would be nice if I could show the selcetion of this loop without the copy option on the excel sheet. In this case I have to create a range which is updated each time by the loop and at the end I have to print the range? Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much. I solved it in this way to make a bit more compact:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
Dim c As Integer
Dim c2 As Integer
c = 0
c2 = 0
    For i = 1 To 119 Step 3
        c2 = c2 + 1
        c = c2 + 120
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).Copy Cells(c, 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to select the range to be copied without actually copying anything:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
Dim rngCopy As Range    

    For i = 1 To 119 Step 3            
        If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
            Set rngCopy = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4))
        Else
            Set rngCopy = Application.Union(rngCopy, _
                          Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)) )
        End If    
    Next i

    rngCopy.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: that works great. I have question, in this case Set stores the ranges by each iteration, am I right?

Comment: Thak you for answering. I don't understand the else condition. What Application.Union do? Thanks again.

Comment: It joins two (or more) separate ranges to create a new range containing both of the original ranges.  It's how you construct a range using a loop.